# How to clean executable using make clean?

Tags: make, makefile

After compiling several *.c and *.h files using make, I cleaned up the object files using make clean. However I don't know how to remove the executable.

my makefile code -->

```
    CC=gcc
    CFLAGS=-I.
    mp1: main.o downloader.o json.o
            $(CC) -o mp1 main.o downloader.o json.o -I.
    .PHONY : clean
    clean :
           -rm *.o $(objects)
```

Answer (score 7):

Your executable seems to be the file `mp1`. Add this file to the `rm` command in the `clean` target:

```
clean :
       -rm *.o $(objects) mp1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sudo make clean
```

The above mentioned command will clean all the `.o` files

Comment: it would clean all and not only the .o files right?

Comment: -1 No, in the current state of the Makefile `make clean` will run `rm *.o $(objects)`, which doesn't clean the executable (assuming that the executable is `mp1` and not in `$(objects)`).

Answer (score -2):

This command is useful when `make` is not available in your system.

`$ find coding/ -type f -executable | xargs rm`

This command removes all executable files in the `coding` directory.

The first part of the command, the `find` part lists all the files which are executable.

The second part of the command takes the input from 1st part and gives it to `rm` command.

`xargs` - a command that converts its standard input into arguments of another program, look the man page for more info